# structuring the array in required way while using jqplots

Tags: php, arrays, jqplot

I am using jqplot to show data in a graph.I am able to fetch data in the array ,but I have a small problem 
to plot data the format is

```
[["Pens",10],["Pencils",30],["Erasers",40],["Charts",3]]
```

I am getting data in the following format

```
[["Pens"],["10"],["Pencils"],["30"],["Erasers"],["40"],["Charts"],["3"]]
```

my code is as follows

**PHP Code**

```
$dbname = 'dbname';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'password1!';
try {
    /* Establish the database connection */
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT Compliancestatus,value FROM COUNT_VALUE WHERE Zone='PZ' and country='AU' and `Compliancestatus` is not null");
    $jsonTable = json_encode($rows);
    print_r($jsonTable);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
//mysql_close($conn);
$conn = null;
$rows = array();
foreach ($result as $r) {
    $rows[] = array($r['Compliancestatus']);
// Values of each slice
    $rows[] = array($r['value']);
}
```

please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
$rows[] = array($r['Compliancestatus']);
// Values of each slice
$rows[] = array($r['value']);
```

To

```
$rows[] = array($r['Compliancestatus'],(int)$r['value']);
```

Comment: hi Joni it is working but value is coming as a string but i need it in the integer form i,e ["Compliance",50] this way but it is coming like this ["Compliance","50"]